# How to aggregate over dynamic fields in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to aggregate over dynamic fields (different for different documents) via elasticsearch. Documents are like following:

```
[{
   "name": "galaxy note",
   "price": 123,
   "attributes": {
      "type": "phone",
      "weight": "140gm"
   }
},{
   "name": "shirt",
   "price": 123,
   "attributes": {
      "type": "clothing",
      "size": "m"
   }
}]
```

As you can see attributes change across documents. What Im trying to achieve is to aggregate fields of these attributes, like so:

```
{
     aggregations: {
         types: {
             buckets: [{key: 'phone', count: 123}, {key: 'clothing', count: 12}]
         }
     }
}
```

I am trying [aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) feature of elasticsearch to achieve this, but not able to find correct way. Is it possible to achieve via aggregation ? Or should I start looking in to [facets](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html), thought it seem to be depricated.

Answer (score 16):

You have to define attributes as nested in your mapping and change the layout of the single attribute values to the fixed layout `{ key: DynamicKey, value: DynamicValue }`

```
PUT /catalog
{
  "settings" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 1
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "article": {
      "properties": {
        "name": { 
          "type" : "string", 
          "index" : "not_analyzed" 
        },
        "price": { 
          "type" : "integer" 
        },
        "attributes": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "key": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

You may than index your articles like this

```
POST /catalog/article
{
  "name": "shirt",
  "price": 123,
  "attributes": [
    { "key": "type", "value": "clothing"},
    { "key": "size", "value": "m"}
  ]
}

POST /catalog/article
{
  "name": "galaxy note",
  "price": 123,
  "attributes": [
    { "key": "type", "value": "phone"},
    { "key": "weight", "value": "140gm"}
  ]
}
```

After all you are then able to aggregate over the nested attributes

```
GET /catalog/_search
{
  "query":{
    "match_all":{}
  },     
  "aggs": {
    "attributes": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "attributes"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "key": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "attributes.key"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "value": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "attributes.value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which then gives you the information you requested in a slightly different form

```
[...]
"buckets": [
  {
    "key": "type",
    "doc_count": 2,
    "value": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "clothing",
        "doc_count": 1
      }, {
        "key": "phone",
        "doc_count": 1
      }
      ]
    }
  },
[...]
```

Comment: Could you please tell how one can filter over dynamic fields and get appropriate fileds' counts in response? Question from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839096/filter-over-dynamic-nested-fields-with-aggregation

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but this is fairly simple with basic aggregation functionality. Beware I did not include a mapping so with type of multiple words you are getting double results.

```
POST /product/atype
{
   "name": "galaxy note",
   "price": 123,
   "attributes": {
      "type": "phone",
      "weight": "140gm"
   }
}

POST /product/atype
{
   "name": "shirt",
   "price": 123,
   "attributes": {
      "type": "clothing",
      "size": "m"
   }
}

GET /product/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "byType": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "attributes.type",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was trying this, but problem is that attributes are not fixed (and also not meant to be fixed), is it possible to do something like attributes.* ?

Comment: So you are saying the key `attributes` is not fixed? Or the key `attributes.type` is not fixed? From your example, everything looks pretty fixed to me. What is not fixed exactly?

Comment: Same here!  Need an answer to this question.

Comment: Meaning `attributes` is fixed, everything inside `attributes` are not, one doc might have `attributes.size` and `attributes.weight`, other doc might have `attributes.width`, `attributes.color`, `attributes.release` and `attributes.matrial` god knows what other doc might have.