# elastic search aggregation with dynamic factes

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to aggregate over dynamic fields, similar to the question:
[How to aggregate over dynamic fields in elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800545/how-to-aggregate-over-dynamic-fields-in-elasticsearch)

below comment helped me do that,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32065070/5129194

Now I am stuck with selecting the dynamic fields,

"buckets": [
  {
    "key": "color_family",
    "doc_count": 2,
    "value": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "white",
        "doc_count": 1
      }, {
        "key": "black",
        "doc_count": 1
      }
      ]
    }
{
    "key": "paper color",
    "doc_count": 2,
    "value": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "white",
        "doc_count": 3
      }, {
        "key": "green",
        "doc_count": 1
      }
      ]
    }
  },

When I do something like below: I get all color_family and all white, where as it should be just white from color_family.

```
    {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "attributes.key": "color_family"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "attributes.value": "white"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

I am looking for it to work more like a normal facet, please let me know if any has solved this before.

Comment: Where is your aggregation query? I only see the filter and the result.

Comment: It is same as in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800545/how-to-aggregate-over-dynamic-fields-in-elasticsearch/32065070#32065070